# What resources are allocated to a medium sized business's cloud implementation?

Tags: server, resources, salesforce

Jump to the accepted answer to see why the question doesn't actually have a distinct answer. And (LFMM) remember not to google too specifically when you don't know what you're looking for.

When a business purchases 200 licenses and is using the enterprise Salesforce CRM, what resources are allocated to that instance, and what operations within Salesforce are handled outside those dedicated resources?

Edit:

This can be helpful to know for interacting with an instance in numerous circumstances, least of which is their APIs.

Comment: Customer service questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a pretty difficult question to answer. Just by doing a little googling the only thing I am sure of is that record limits are the only thing tied to the [amount of user licenses an organization buys.](http://www.developerforce.com/media/ForcedotcomBookLibrary/Force.com_Multitenancy_WP_101508.pdf) - Page 10

All orgs are still bound by the [specified limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)

The key here is cpu time is used as a limit. Does an organization with 1k license have a better CPU than an org with 20 users? I can't find documentation to support that, but you would have to imagine some resources would scale. But then you also look at Memory usage and that's the same across the board regardless of users.

You might want to search more on salesforce multi-tenancy. Here are some links to browse

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrKA3cJmoms

Comment: Will do some reading, thanks for the links. I've seen some before, but the Youtube video at least is brand new to me. I wonder if anyone outside a few hardware engineers actually knows real specifics. Not just cores, but threads, clock speeds (cpu and ram), data transfers speeds etc. I know it can get very granular and hard to interpret, but even if someone could say it's 4gb of ram with 2 dual-threaded cores that'd be great. The rest can be figured out(for practical applications at least) through timing test scripts and some arithmetic

Comment: I lied, different article than I thought - good stuff. Once I get through it all, and understand it all, I think it's at least going to make my question irrelevant and force me to pose another. -- thank you